# Filter columns with a dropdown

Tags: google-sheets-filter, google-sheets-macro

I need your help with a somewhat dynamic drop down filter.
I have a drop down list in cell B6 that states categories that appear in column "E".
Below the drop down list I have a table with 5 columns (B-F), Column E contains multiple categories/ types separated by a comma, (All, Tech & Talent, Growth, Market Expansion, Divest, Acquihire) F contains an if statement `=IF(REGEXMATCH(E10,$B$6), 1, 0)` simply put this states if the cell in column "E" contains the same category that was selected in "B6" then give me "1" else give me "0".

I tried to amend existing code to have the current spreadsheet filter based on the selected drop down. The below code did not work. I also tried simplifying to range to the entire sheet but as you make any edit on the sheet regardless of what it is it will filter column F.

```
function myFunction() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('B6').activate();
var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
.setHiddenValues([''])
.build();
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4, criteria);
};
```

Can someone help give guidance on how to restructure the code OR alternatively if there is a cleaner easier method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  // Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp, SlidesApp, or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Clear Filter', 'removeFilter')
      .addItem('Set Filter', 'setFilter')
      .addToUi();
}

// remove any existing filter
function removeFilter() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter) {
    filter.remove();
  }
}

// set the filter for a value of 1 in Column F
function setFilter() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()

  // define the filter range
  var last_row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().filter(String).length;
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: last row= "+last_row)
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,last_row,6)
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the range is "+range.getA1Notation())

  // establish criteria
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria();

  // define the values to hide
  var HideValues = [0]
  // the filtered column
  var HideCol = 6

  // create the filter, build the criteria and set the filter
  var filter = range.createFilter();
  criteria.setHiddenValues(HideValues).build();
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(HideCol, criteria);

  // Logger.log("DEBUG: filter is set")
}
```

**Data Validation and functions**

- The category list in Column K is a list of all the potential categories.
- The Category Selector in cell I1 is a Data Validation cell based on the range= $K$2:$K$8
- The formula for the "Selection Flag" is in cell F2 - `=arrayformula(IF(REGEXMATCH(D2:D9,$I$1), 1, 0))`

  - this populates the flag value for all of the data rows.

**Script Logic**

- a custom menu is created so that the filter can be reset.

  - You *could* create an `onEdit(e)` script based on the Category Selector, and you *could* modify the `removeFilter` script to delete the filter before the new filter is created.
- the key differences between this script and the OP are:

  - creation of the range: `var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,last_row,6)`

    - the range is calculated dynamically.
    - I moved this up to row#1, but the location of the range is not important so long as the "Category Selector" and "Category List" are *outside* the table range.
  - simplified declaration of the criteria.
  - the "hidden" value = 0 (zero)  rather than an empty value.

---

**Category List**

[image: categories]

**Category selector**

[image: selector]

**Unfiltered Data**

[image: unfiltered]

**Filtered data**

[image: filtered]